# New Pine editor v5 function "request.security_lower_tf()" not working on active candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4, pine-editor

**This is what I'm aiming to achieve:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WgXn.png)

This is the function I'm referring to:

```
//@version=5
indicator("`request.security_lower_tf()` Example", overlay = true)

// If the current chart timeframe is set to 120 minutes, then the `arrayClose` array will contain two 'close' values from the 60 minute timeframe for each bar.
arrClose  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "60", close)

if bar_index == last_bar_index - 1
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(arrClose))
```

**Where the issue is:**

- this function displays lower timeframe candles for an **already closed candle** (past candle)
- What I want is...**to display past candles** (already closed)...**AND current active candles**

If I go and change this part:

```
if bar_index == last_bar_index - 1
```

...with this part:

```
if bar_index == last_bar_index
```

...it **displays (on-screen)** the correct data (past candles + active candles)...and then it disappears from screen...as if it flashes for a few seconds and then data is gone.

Why does it do that? Out of range? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to be fixed.
Please check again, it looks like everything is working as expected now.